# How to integrate Phantomjs with my web project to capture Screenshot?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, webpage-screenshot

I have one HTML Page and its have Payment Module somewhere. I want to capture that Payment Module Screenshot and need to store in Database using PhantomJS.

Is there any way to integrate "[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)" with my single page JavaScript web application to capture DOM screenshot with pixel perfect styling ?

Is is possible to do so with PhantomJS? or you can suggest the best solution to do so.

Thanks

Abhishek

Comment: Why do you think you need PhantomJS? What task are you tryiing to solve?

Comment: Hey @Vaviloff I am trying to capture some section from my webpage on Clicking on some button and send that captured image to and api to store the same screenshot in my Database. Let me know if is there any way to integrate PhantomJS Screen Capture with web page.